# Syntax to read a file from while-do loop in shell script

Tags: shell

This shell script contains a while loop:

```
while IFS = \| read SourceDB db_name Mysql_table hdfsdir libpath
do
    # jobs

done < $/root/SqoopWrapper/InputFile

exit 0
```

The shell script contains an input file that I want to loop

On execution, am getting

> " syntax error near unexpected token `done "

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Semicolons seem to be missing from your expression, syntax for a while loop is something like this:
while true;do echo "something";done

Comment: My question is how to make the InputFile.txt contents to be read to process further scripts. I've modified my **script** as following: ensure if my script is correct on echoing the variable $input it did not echoed the contents of InputFile.

`input=/root/SqoopWrapper1/InputFile.txt
IFS='|'
while read SourceDB db_name Mysql_table hdfsdir libpath
do
#process
done < $input
exit 0 `

Comment: @babsaai Semicolons are only needed if everything's on the same line.

Comment: Please clear all the simple errors by testing your script in [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). That will help you to get rid of the incorrect spaces around the `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the spaces in the assignment.

```
while IFS=\| read SourceDB db_name Mysql_table hdfsdir libpath
```

You can use [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/) to catch these kinds of errors in the future.

```
$ shellcheck myscript

Line 1:
while IFS = \| read SourceDB db_name Mysql_table hdfsdir libpath
      ^-- SC2162: read without -r will mangle backslashes.
          ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.
```